# How do I access OneDrive application folder using the Graph .NET SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to create a file withion the application folder using the Graph .Net SDK.
I can find a class SpecialFolder but i cannot workout how to use the class to enable me to create a file within the application folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a collection of samples how to use the SDK in the  [aspnet-snippets-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/blob/master/Graph-ASPNET-46-Snippets/Microsoft%20Graph%20ASPNET%20Snippets/Models/FilesService.cs)

Here's the snippet for creating a file:

```
// Create a text file in the current user's root directory.
        public async Task<List<ResultsItem>> CreateFile(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
        {
            List<ResultsItem> items = new List<ResultsItem>();

            // Create the file to upload. Read the file content string into a stream that gets passed as the file content.
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string fileName = Resource.File + guid.Substring(0, 8) + ".txt";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Resource.FileContent_New);

            using (MemoryStream fileContentStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {

                // Add the file.
                DriveItem file = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileContentStream);

                if (file != null)
                {

                    // Get file properties.
                    items.Add(new ResultsItem
                    {
                        Display = file.Name,
                        Id = file.Id,
                        Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            { Resource.Prop_Created, file.CreatedDateTime.Value.ToLocalTime() },
                            { Resource.Prop_Url, file.WebUrl },
                            { Resource.Prop_Id, file.Id }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return items;
        }
```